# Augmented reality - Multi support - webapp

Tags: web-applications, 3d, device, augmented-reality

Do you know how I could do augmented reality in these conditions:

via browser
Multi media (tablets, computer)
Without flash (for iOS)
No native app (or so that can encapsulate in a web page, if it exists)
Without WebGL or other solution that require the latest version & patch the browser to operate. I do not demand IE 6 but for example it took FF, May 15, I got the version of May 11 to a page works

And the augmented reality element is a interactive 3d file...

That's it, thank you very much in advance for you to be considered the subject, I find no satisfactory after several days of searching

Comment: Take a look at this project: https://code.google.com/p/jsc3d/ they render 3d with just JS + Canvas.

Comment: Ty it's help me a little. I go to see that more.